# Cannot access a variable in a codeigniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

I am trying to access an array set in a model from a codeigniter controller, and things are acting odd.

Currently all I have in the model is this:

```
class Pages_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    var $pages = array(
        'draw', 'stackoverflow', 'words'
    );
}
```

I can see the array is being set because when I execute

```
$this->load->model('Pages_model');
die(var_dump(get_object_vars($this->Pages_model)));
```

I get the output

```
array
  'pages' => 
    array
      0 => string 'draw' (length=4)
      1 => string 'stackoverflow' (length=13)
      2 => string 'words' (length=5)
```

But when I try to access the variable itself:

```
 $this->load->model('Pages_model');
 die(var_dump($this->Pages_model->$pages));
```

I get an error:

> Message: Undefined variable: pages

This does not make any sense to me. What is going on????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try $this->Pages_model->pages, without the $ before pages.

When you do this:

```
$this->Pages_model->$pages
```

PHP tries to evaluate the variable of $pages, which is null (Pages_model->*null*).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can directly access variables in a model I believe you can only call functions, perhaps make a getter function for the variable and return the variable. eg.

**Model Page**

```
function get_pages() {
   return this->pages;
}
```

**Controller**

```
$pages = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
```

Comment: Missing '$' from this->pages. And this comes down to personal preference I think... Getter functions are only really used if the variables aren't set as public. It's common practice to delcare the variables in a class/model and then to call the model's variables outside of it once the class has been instantiated and calling the models functions to get, set and update the variables as necessary. Feel free to correct me here.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variable directly, if you define it like this :

```
class Pages_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->pages = array(
        'draw', 'stackoverflow', 'words'
    );
    }

}
```

Then you would call it by: `$this->pages_model->pages`

Answer (score 0):

Make static member:

```
class Model_name {
        static $member='nothing';
}
//and use it with scope resolution operator '::'
$m = new Model_name();
echo $m::member; //output: nothing
$m::member = 'something';
echo $m::member; //output: something
```